# Why does a function return the error "list index out of range" in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, primes

This code was written in Python 3. I am trying to find the 10001st prime number.

```
#10001st prime number
mylist=[]
def prime_index(n):
    for i in range(99**99):
        for x in range(2, int(i**1/2)):
            if i % x == 0:
                return False
            return True
            mylist.append(i)
        n=int(n+1)
        print(mylist[n])
        break
prime_index(10001)
```

When I run, it says "list index out of range", referring to `print(mylist[n])`.
However I have been adding primes to the list along the way in the `mylist.append(i)`. So can someone tell me what is the problem here because I do not understand what is going on. Is 99**99 too small? Or more subtle problem with code?

Comment: I think you'll be surprised at the value of `n` when the `print()` executes. Add some debug print statements to your code to determine what's happening as it executes; in this way you can watch your code run. In particular, print out the value of `n` just before the print() executes so that you can see what index into the array that your code is attempting to display.

Comment: As it stands your code reaches the offending line the first time when `mylist` still has length 0.

Comment: `range(99**99)` produces a list of numbers that has nothing to do with `mylist`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `int(n+1)`, just use `n+1`.

Comment: Probably the `n=n+1` and `print` statements should be after the `for` loop. And you shouldn't have `break`, since that means the loop will only run once.

Comment: why would you want to append 10000 primes to a list before getting your 10001th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`99**99` is not too small; if you actually print it, you're well beyond what you need (if you tried to run it out, you'd never finish, it's 657 bits of work). But your loop makes no sense; your inner loop will return either `True` or `False` immediately if it executes even once.

"Luckily" for you, it never executes even once. The first outer loop sets `i` to 0 the first time, so the inner loop doesn't run at all (side-note, you probably want `i ** (1/2)`, not `i ** 1 / 2`; exponentiation has higher precedence than division). Because it doesn't run, you end up indexing into an empty list (and asking for index 10001 no less).

There are far too many problems in this code to address them all; look for other trial division prime finding code to get an idea of what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to print out the 10001st element as soon as you find (or not) the first prime.  Also, note that you return from the routine without finding *any* prime number -- if you were to get that far.  There is no way to reach the **append** statement.

You got to the **print** statement only because your first iteration has i = 0, so you don't enter the **for** loop at all.

Please follow the posting guidelines: take the time to research how to generate prime numbers.  It can be much faster than you're doing, and will give you a nice, succinct bit of code to put into your program.